# MacOS Recovery error: "The recovery server could not be contacted"

Tags: macos, recovery

"The recovery server could not be contacted" is thrown, when attempting to reinstall MacOS.

Laptop: MacBook Pro 2016,  https://support.apple.com/kb/SP748?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Accessed via "Command-R".

Guides suggest to check internet connection, date or try later. All 3 above points are double-checked and fine.

What could be the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Answer found on https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251177226

**Option-Command-R** was a solution, which started *different* Recovery image for **Monterey** version (proceeding successfully), while **Command-R** was attempting  to install **Sierra** (and failing with "The recovery server could not be contacted").

> If macOS Sierra 10.12.4 or later was never installed on your Mac, macOS Recovery works differently:

> - Command-R is still the recommended way to start up from macOS Recovery. This combination makes sure that the installation isn't associated with your Apple ID, which is important if you're selling or giving away your Mac.
> - Option-Command-R installs the macOS that came with your Mac, or the **closest version** still available.
> - Shift-Option-Command-R **isn't available**.

P.S. Below are lists of OS<>laptop model compatibility, thanks to @DavidAnderson for comment

- [macOS Monterey is compatible with these computers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212551) (MacOS 12)
- [macOS Ventura is compatible with these computers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213264) (MacOS 13)

Comment: Which version of macOS did you have before trying to reinstall? Which version of macOS did you want to install?

Comment: @DavidAnderson, cannot answer about "before". Which I wanted? Any working. I got laptop with a screwed OS. By the logic of these shortcuts (and https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904#notupdated), I suggest it was Sierra (but updated, not installed afresh). 
Another assumption is that there is no Sierra distributive for this older MacBook, and the only way to get Sierra is to upgrade from older OS. If this is a case, then error message is VERY misleading.

Comment: OK. [Monterey](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212551) (macOS 12) is the latest version of macOS that is compatible for your Mac. Your Mac is not on the list for [Venture](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213264) (macOS 13). IMO, Monterey is the version you would want to have installed.

Comment: @DavidAnderson yes, that exactly what happened - Monterey was installed successfully. Thank you for the OS-Mac model compatibility links! Edding to the answer